# Make Test.QuickCheck.Batch use a default type for testing list functions

Tags: testing, haskell, type-inference, quickcheck

I am testing a function called extractions that operates over any list.

```
extractions :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
extractions [] = []
extractions l = extract l []
    where extract [] _ = []
          extract (x:xs) prev = (x, prev++xs) : extract xs (x : prev)
```

I want to test it, for example, with

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Batch    
prop_len l = length l == length (extractions l)
main = runTests "extractions" defOpt [run prop_len]
```

But this won't compile; I have to supply a type either for `run` or `prop_len`, because QuickCheck can't generate `[a]`, it has to generate something concrete. So I chose `Int`:

```
main = runTests "extractions" defOpt [r prop_len]
    where r = run :: ([Int] -> Bool) -> TestOptions -> IO TestResult
```

Is there any way to get QuickCheck to choose `a` for me instead of having it specified in the type of `run`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [quickcheck manual](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#5) says "no":

> Properties must have monomorphic types. `Polymorphic' properties, such as the one above, must be restricted to a particular type to be used for testing. It is convenient to do so by stating the types of one or more arguments in a
>
> where types = (x1 :: t1, x2 :: t2, ...)
>
> clause...